# running line after line in text file as mySQL query (cmd)

Tags: mysql, for-loop, cmd, while-loop

I have a text file where **each** line is a mySQL query. 
I would like to know how to run the queries line by line (loop) using cmd.
Only know the following:

```
mysql -h[host] -u[user] -p < input.txt
```

How can I create a loop in the cmd that runs on the txt file not only once, but line by line and execute each query?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - your solution would work... Are you looking for separate output files, as opposed to a single that the above would produce? (if so - how are the files to be named?)

Comment: @John i edited my post to make it clearer. actually, the output part wasn't the main problem.

Comment: @John The main thing is how to write this loop code so it could make n iterations (n = number of lines in the txt file) and in each, to run the relevant line as a query. the results can be just displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found my answer- very simple but I didn't think of it: First i used `CONCAT()` to add `;` at the end of each query in the text file (named input.sql). This was the important part. Then I used this:

`mysql -h host -u user -p < input.sql >> output.txt`